# How to use nc to send message consecutively per second

Tags: bash, shell-script, nc

I'm learning the Apache Flink. Here is the Hello World of Flink: https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/getting-started/tutorials/local_setup.html

This example is a program, which counts the words in every 5 seconds.

If we want to run this sample, we need to do the following steps:

- Execute `nc -l 9000` on one terminal (A);
- Execute `./bin/flink run examples/streaming/SocketWindowWordCount.jar --port 9000` on another terminal (B);
- Go to the terminal A and type some words.

If we `Ctrl-c` on the terminal A, this sample will be terminated.

I want to know if it is possible to type the words programmatically at the terminal A. For example, I want to type the word `lol` per second at the terminal A, what should I do?

The code below won't work.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    echo 'lol' | nc -l 9000
    sleep 1
done
```

Of course, I may try to modify the `SocketWindowWordCount.java` to do so but for now, for some reason, I can not change the java code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe the whole loop into `nc`:

```
while true; do
    echo 'lol'
    sleep 1
done | nc -l 9000
```

This will start a single instance of `nc`, listening for connections on port 9000, and send “lol” once per second to it.

Note that “lol”s will accumulate until the connection is opened, so you might see a number of “lol”s send immediately on connection. You could add a delay at the start:

```
(sleep 5
 while true; do
     echo 'lol'
     sleep 1
 done) | nc -l 9000
```